# Deletar arquivos por extensão

Tags: c#, arquivo

Como posso deletar arquivos de uma pasta por extensão? "Peguei" os arquivos com este código:

```
string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(st.path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Mas não sei deletar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como tens uma coleção de `string`s com os caminhos dos arquivos, pode usar o método [`Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) da classe `File`.

```
foreach(var arq in arquivos)
{
    File.Delete(arq);
}
```